# Mixins in Scala 3

Tags: scala, mixins, scala-3

I am working on upgrading some code from Scala 2.13 to Scala 3 and I came across some differences with trait mixins with inner traits having same names.

This code compiles in Scala 2.13:

```scala
trait First {
    val first: Service

    trait Service {
        def someMethod(): Int
    }
}

trait LiveFirst extends First {
    override val first: Service = new Service {
        override def someMethod(): Int = 1
    }
}

trait Second {
    val second: Service

    trait Service {
        def someMethod(): Int
    }
}

trait LiveSecond extends Second {
    override val second: Service = new Service {
        override def someMethod(): Int = 2
    }
}

type Mixed = First with Second
val mixed: Mixed = new LiveFirst with LiveSecond
```

But fails with following compiler error in Scala 3:

```
[error] 32 |val mixed: Mixed = new LiveFirst with LiveSecond
[error]    |                   ^
[error]    |error overriding trait Service in trait First;
[error]    |  trait Service in trait Second cannot be used here - class definitions cannot be overridden
```

What exactly has changed here?

Comment: maybe it's https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/class-shadowing.html ?

Comment: As a workaround, `Service` can be extracted: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/NSI60rn2Qb2oiZKMsq76cA/3 or even https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/NSI60rn2Qb2oiZKMsq76cA/6